# PresentModel View Controller Problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, presentmodalviewcontroller

Hi Every one I have have a problem with present model view Controller. Here's the scenario:

1. This is navigation bar application I have a UIViewController class in which I add another class of `UIView` Controller by using this statement `[self.view addSubView:controllerClass]`;
2. In controllerClass I have insert tab bar at the bottom and also write its delegates on each tab bar click i'll add another `UIViewController` class to it as a subView but i'll make the height or frame to this controller is `(0,0,320,369)`. so that tab bar shown through out when we click on different tabs.
3. By clicking on first tab say ScannerViewController add a subview. There is a gallery button in this View. when user clicks on it a presentModel View Controller Insert to it and hide the navigation bar when i select the image from the gallery and make navigation bar `hidden =NO` , it dosen't work and the tab bar on bottom was disappeared.

Comment: The modalviewcontroller has a navigation bar by default and it can be used only with navigation based apps. Otherwise for normal apps and tabbar based apps the y coordinate of the objects on the screen will be affected. That is the navigation bar which comes with the modalview controller will take some place moving the tabBar down.

Comment: And moreover you have to initiate the subview (controllerclass) with the tabbar (should not add it manually)making it as a tabbarbased view controller.

Comment: I am adding tabBar by using interfaceBuilder and make the sizes of controllers which insert on tabclick is (0,0,320,369)

Comment: Present model View Controller working fine when i add it but after that Views Indentation get changed

Comment: -1: Please do not solicit upvotes through chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1150276#1150276). If the answer/question is good, the upvotes will come naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're abusing the tab bar construct.  Each tab on the tab bar should have it's own UINavigationController rather than sharing one controller per tab.

Also, in my experience it's best to present the modal view controller using the AppDelegate's lowest level view.  I.e. the view that was added to the UIWindow object when the app started.